# When I try to run Spring MVC using STS then I get The requested resource () is not available

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am newbie in Spring MVC and Spring/Hibernate altogether.

I am trying to run example which I found on net try to do it and not able to sucessfully run it.

My web.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>    

</web-app>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="net.roseindia" />


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!-- 
<mvc:annotation-driven />
-->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.Article</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="hibernatetransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

my ArticleController.java is as follows

```
package net.roseindia.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.roseindia.model.Article;
import net.roseindia.service.ArticleService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

  @Autowired
  private ArticleService articleService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView saveArticle(@ModelAttribute(" article") Article  article,
        BindingResult result) {
     articleService.addArticle( article);
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView listArticles() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("articles",  articleService.listArticles());

     return new ModelAndView("articlesList", model);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article,
         BindingResult result) {
    return new ModelAndView("addArticle");
  }

}
```

Can somebody please help me to solve this error?

Thanking you in advance.

Thanks, 
Krunal Shah

Comment: I have solved this problem. 

In web.xml I had 

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 

I changed it to 

    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>

Which solved this requested resource is not available problem.

I thought it may help someone like me. As I copied this code straight from net and didn't have a clue what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the below steps should solve this specific problem

Right click on the project --> properties --> Deployment Assembly --> Add

You can add all your folder
(e.g. Source: /src/main/java --> Deploy Path :  WEB-INF/classes)
to a specific Deploy path

I think this will help some.